# Is there any way to inherit from TriggerAction class?

Tags: wpf, inheritance, storyboard, eventtrigger

I am not interested in animations and I am trying to make simple setter action to be set without key frames.

I wanted to inherit TriggerAction; make properties that set the new value on target, any additional optional properties so I can use:

```
<EventTrigger SourceName="btn" RoutedEvent="Click">
    <BooleanActionTrigger TargetName="cb" Property="IsChecked" Value="False"/>
</EventTrigger>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to have Expression Blend installed. [System.Windows.Interactivity for WPF](http://nuget.org/packages/System.Windows.Interactivity.WPF/) is now available on NuGet. Simply add that NuGet package to your project and write your custom `TriggerAction`:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Interactivity;

public class MyCustomAction : TriggerAction<DependencyObject>
{
    ...
}
```